# SQLite NullPointerException when calling insert()

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I get NullPointerException whenever I try to insert new records to db 
I am not sure if the problem occurs in creation or opening 
here is my SQLiteHelper class:

```
public MySQLiteHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
 }
private static final String DB_CREATE_QUERY   = "CREATE TABLE "+TAB_NAME+" (" +
        ""+COL_ID+" integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
        ""+COL_xxxLE+" LONG," +
        ""+COL_UxxxILE+" LONG," +
        ""+COL_xxxFI+" LONG," +
        ""+COL_xxxxIFI+" LONG,"+
        ""+COL_DATE+" DATETIME  );";

private static final String DB_CREATE_QUERY_TEMP   = "CREATE TABLE "+TAB_NAME_TEMP+" (" +
        ""+COL_ID+" integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
        ""+COLxxILE+" LONG," +
        ""+COL_xxILE+" LONG," +
        ""+COL_xxFI+" LONG," +
        ""+COLxxxWIFI+" LONG,"+
        ""+COLxxxDATE+" DATETIME ) ;";

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database){
    try {
        database.execSQL(DB_CREATE_QUERY);
        database.execSQL(DB_CREATE_QUERY_TEMP);
    } catch (SQLiteException exc)
    {
        Log.e("SQL",exc.toString());
    }
}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    Log.w("TAHA->","Upgrading database from version: "+oldVersion+" to "+newVersion+". This will destroy all existing data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TAB_NAME);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TAB_NAME_TEMP);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

this is my RecordSource.java where I insert records

public class RecordSource {

```
private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase database;

private String[] myColumns =
        {
                MySQLiteHelper.xxxLE,
                MySQLiteHelper.xxxxILE,
                MySQLiteHelper.xxxxFI,
                MySQLiteHelper.xxxxIFI,
};
/**
 *CONSTRUCTOR
 * calling MySQLiteHelper class which maintains my DB each time
 * to make sure my DB is ready
 */
public RecordSource(Context context)
{
    dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
}



/**
 * Open and close methods, used to free memory
 * @throws SQLiteException
 */
public void open() throws SQLiteException
{
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

}

public void close()
{
    dbHelper.close();
}


public boolean createRecord(boolean firstLaunch)
{
    if(firstLaunch)
        freshStart();
    else {
        Record rec = new Record( getLastRecord("temp_record"), true);
        insertRecord(rec, MySQLiteHelper.TAB_NAME);
        Log.w("taha->", "another record inserted");
    }
    return true;
}

public void freshStart()
{
    Record firstRecord = new Record();
    insertRecord(firstRecord, MySQLiteHelper.TAB_NAME_TEMP);
    Record rec = new Record( getLastRecord("temp_record"), true);
    insertRecord(rec,MySQLiteHelper.TAB_NAME);
    Log.w("taha->", "fresh record inserted");
}
public boolean insertRecord(Record rec,String tab)
{
    ContentValues rec_values = new ContentValues();
    rec_values.put(myColumns[0],rec.getDown_mobile());
    rec_values.put(myColumns[1],rec.getUp_mobile());
    rec_values.put(myColumns[2],rec.getDown_wifi());
    rec_values.put(myColumns[3],rec.getUp_wifi());

    try {
        database.insert(tab, null, rec_values);
    } catch (SQLiteException ex)
    {
        Log.w("taha->", ex.toString());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and I call it from a MyService

```
 Context ctx = getApplicationContext();

                    rec = new RecordSource(context);
```

this is the error

```
  Process: com.xx.xx.nxxr, PID: 16742
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.xxxr.RecordSource.insertRecord(RecordSource.java:105)
        at com.xxer.RecordSource.freshStart(RecordSource.java:83)
        at comxxxher.RecordSource.createRecord(RecordSource.java:71)
        at com.xxxer.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:43)
```

I checked in the db file and the database exists but database variable is always null

Comment: can you please give us the implementation of the insertRecord() method?

Comment: Sorry for that, I edited my post and added missing methods

Comment: why in your service have this? rec = new RecordSource(context); and the name of your context is ctx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your createRecord() method to this:

```
public boolean createRecord(boolean firstLaunch)
{
    open();
    if(firstLaunch)
        freshStart();
    else {
        Record rec = new Record( getLastRecord("temp_record"), true);
        insertRecord(rec, MySQLiteHelper.TAB_NAME);
        Log.w("taha->", "another record inserted");
    }
    close();
return true;
}
```

for your info you have to open and close the database before and after any query

Comment: new error in database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

Comment: ok i think i found it. in RecordSource class change your private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper; to this:   private SQLiteOpenHelper dbHelper;